# How to automatically populate Active Directory hashedPassword field using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hash, scripting, active-directory, ldap

I'm working with a client who is attempting to import AD users via `PowerShell`. The following command is being used as an initial test:

```
New-ADUser -Name "John Smith" `
           -SamAccountName Smithbor `
           -GivenName John `
           -Surname Smith `
           -EmailAddress john.smith@stackoverflow.com `
           -Path 'OU=Users,DC=stackoverflow,DC=com' `
           -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
           -Enabled $true `
           -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "foo12345678" -Force)
```

This appears to work, in that it correctly creates an AD user, however the `hashedPassword` field is not being populated, and this `hashedPassword` field is required for some further integration. Is there a way to automatically populate the `hashedPassword` field at this stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the password setting can fail due to password policy restrictions. You could try using `Set-ADAccountPassword` to set the password after the account has been created.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity username -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "password" -Force)
```